# Variable indefinida, laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Me encuentro con un error inusual, tengo una variable indefinida que en realidad si esta definida, este es el codigo.

```
public function excelestados(Request $request){
        $registrado = \Auth::user()->tipos_usuarios_id;
        $filtros = \Auth::user()->username;

        if($registrado == 1){
            $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
            Excel::create('ExcelEstados', function($excelestados){
                $excelestados->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet){
                    $conteoestados = usuarios::whereNotNull('asignacion')->get();
                    $conteoestados = json_decode( json_encode($conteoestados), true);
                    $sheet->fromArray($conteoestados);
                    $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
                });
            })->export('xls');      
        }
        if($registrado == 3){
            $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['gestion']);
            Excel::create('ExcelEstados', function($excelestados) {
                $excelestados->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) {
                    $conteoestados = usuarios::whereNotNull('asignacion')->where('asignacion', $filtros)->get();
                    $conteoestados = json_decode( json_encode($conteoestados), true);
                    $sheet->fromArray($conteoestados);
                    $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
                });
            })->export('xls');
        }
    }
```

Si ingreso como admin, este metodo funciona bien, pero si ingreso como gestion, el metodo me dice que la variable $filtro no esta definida, pero en realida si, esta al comienzo del metodo, ya comprobe que en realidad esta variable tuviera valores, y aun asi me sigue apareciendo ese error, a que se debera esto?

ERROR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error que había visto es que usabas `$filtros` pero cuando le asignabas el valor utilizabas `$filtro`, sin la s al final, pero creo que acabas de editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Si la edite.. estaba mal, en realidad es $filtros..  pero aun asi sale el error de variable indefinida, tal cual como aparece ahi.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner exactamente lo que dice el error? si no funciona como visitante, posiblemente tenga que ver con el Auth::user

Comment: Claro, mira arriba actualice la pregunta.

Comment: Intenta con `$conteoestados = usuarios::where("asignacion", $filtros)->get();` no es necesario el `whereNotNull` puesto que ya estás especificando un parámetro.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el usuario gestion no tiene definido los filtros (o el rol en su defecto y este, los filtros) en la tabla, más o menos lo que dice @memoadian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error está en que no se le está pasando/heredando la variable a la función anónima:

```
   Excel::create('ExcelEstados', function($excelestados) use ($filtros) {
       $excelestados->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) use ($filtros) {

           $conteoestados = usuarios::whereNotNull('asignacion')
                       ->where('asignacion', $filtros)
                       ->get();

 // ....
```

Para más información: http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Aunque lo raro es que con el usuario admin le funcione según lo que el comenta.

Comment: @Néstor probablemente cuando ingresa como admin es en `$registrado == 1`

Comment: @Néstor Funciona por que con el usuario `admin` no utiliza dicha variable.

Comment: Bueno, he realizado pruebas con sus sugerencias, me sale el mismo error, aplique un dd($filtros) y el navegador me muestra "gestionad", osea el usuario que necesito, es decir que este ingresa a $registrado == 3 despues de eso compruebo la variable esta bien, pero en la consulta no se admite.

Comment: @zereft ¿cómo así «en la consulta no se admite»?

Comment: Mira esto, si yo pongo dd($filtros); despues de esta linea $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['gestion']);                                                                                       este me arroja resultado positivo, pero, si pongo el dd despues de estas lineas                           $excelestados->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) use ($filtros){      me aparece variable indefinida.

Comment: Es exactamente el mismo problema pero en la línea anterior, revisa la edición y por favor utiliza una mejor **indentación** para ver mejor el código.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, lo tendre en cuenta, y tenias razon.